# Convert multiple files from tsv to csv using pandas and glob

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, glob

While trying to convert the tab separated files (.tsv extension) to comma separated files (.csv extension) from local folder, it converted first two files to .csv but the last 2 files are not converted to .csv.

Here is list of files format :

```
     dir--
          abc.tsv
          red 1.tsv
          yellow 2022.01.20.tsv
          blue 2022.01.28.tsv
```

for the first 2 files will be converting into .csv as successfully. But last 2 files are not being converted as .csv and it's throwing the error like :

> ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

Here is the sample code snippet :

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

tsvfiles = 
glob.glob('C:/Users/xxxx/xxx/xxx/*.tsv') 
for tsv_file in tsvfiles:
    out = tsv_file.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(tsv_file) 
    df.to_csv(out)
```

Comment: @BigBen, I am getting the error at  line [out = tsv_file.split('.')[0]+'.csv']. Because files have the date with . (dot). for first 2 files that condition only satisfy with .csv, But for the last 2 files that is not being satisfied

Comment: you want to convert the ```.tsv``` files to ```.csv``` file and then make a single dataframe?

Comment: @Optimus, yes.. I want to convert the .tsv to .csv files with same filenames

Comment: You can also try this [link](https://gist.github.com/danyaljj/147b7d513001154feeec)

Comment: can you just use `replace()`?

Comment: @JonSG, I think replace might not be worked here.

Comment: @JonSG, for suppose  i have file format like [abcc 1.2.3.tsv] it is considering only abcc 1. But i want to consider the file name as abcc 1.2.3

Comment: This will not work? `"abcc 1.2.3.tsv".replace(".tsv", ".csv")`, if not, the `re.sub()` version with a line end will I bet

Comment: @JonSG, Sorry..for that actually it's working fine for some files. but for some files it's not converting into csv. throwing the error like :  ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = 'Enter your path here'
tsvfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.tsv") 
for t in tsvfiles:
    tsv = pd.read_table(t, sep='\t')
    tsv.to_csv(t[:-4] + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: for suppose, if i have 10 tsv file in one folder, in the same folder files itself converted as csv with the same filenames

Comment: Actually i confused when you asked about single dataframe, but i want to create the every file itself converted from tsv to csv in the same folder

Comment: I am able to convert the files such as [abc 1.tsv', wed 2.tsv']. But i am not able to convert the files format such as [abc 1.2.3.tsv, thur 2.4.3.tsv]. Could you please help me to convert those [abc 1.2.3.tsv, thur 2.4.3.tsv] file format types.

Comment: I am getting the error like : ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

Comment: Its working perfect for me. Are you using my exact code?

Comment: It's working but, for some files it's throwing error like previously i mentioned

Comment: Then I am sure those files are not correct. You should check them first if they are truly ```.tsv``` or not. Moreover, your code did converted the files to ```.csv``` but if you open those CSVs, all the columns are in only one column.

Comment: I have verified. Because of 2 files it's throwing the error. by changing the function name like read_excel(filename), Then it's working fine for the 2 files

Comment: Can we add if..elif conditions for that to handle the functions of read_table() and read_csv()?

Comment: Yes we can add them within the for loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242603/discussion-between-optimus-and-user-98).